# VB.net Find characters in a string then show the text found including the characters

Tags: vb.net, text

I can find text no problem, I am stuck trying to figure out a proper way to find characters, then capture the text following it and including the characters found. So I need a way to modify this code to do something with the text once it is found. I want to look at any text submitted to my form, if it finds specific characters (in this case tkt) I want to msgbox them along with the following characters until a space, a character that is not a letter or number or end of the string. I used the <> to show where I want the tkt number placed.

So for example:

```
Dim strTEST As String = "I am a ticket. My ticket is tkt8937378"
    ' See if tkt is contained in the string.
    If Not strTEST.IndexOf("tkt") = -1 Then
        msgbox("No ticket found")
    Else
        msgbox("Ticket " & <tkt8937378> & " found.")
    End If
```

Comment: IndexOf returns a position number, use that as the next starting point to search for your space of end of line marker, then use SubString to extract that string element out of the root sentence.

Comment: `IndexOf` returns an integer, but also has overloads to start other than the first character. so find the index of the first space after `tkt` (or the max length) and the chars in between the two will be the `SubString()` you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if it finds specific characters (in this case tkt) I want to msgbox
>   them along with the following characters until a space, a character
>   that is not a letter or number or end of the string.

Sounds like a good candidate for [Regex.Match()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you're only expecting **one** ticket in the string:

```
    Dim strTEST As String = "I am a ticket. My ticket is tkt8937378"
    Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(strTEST, "\btkt[0-9a-fA-F]+\b")
    If m.Success Then
        Dim ticket As String = m.Value
        MessageBox.Show("Ticket " & ticket & " found.")
    End If
```

For more than one ticket number in the string, use either a loop with Match(), or switch to the Matches() method.

You can learn more about Regular Expressions at [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

---------- Edit #1 ----------

> Can you have multiple instances in this RegEx? for example to find
>   both tkt and TKT? Or make it NON-Case sensitive?

Sure!  You can make the pattern itself case insensitive by adding `(?i)` to it:

```
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(strTEST, "\b(?i)tkt[0-9a-fA-F]+\b")
```

Alternatively, you can tell `Match()` to be case insensitive by passing a third parameter and using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`:

```
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(strTEST, "\btkt[0-9a-fA-F]+\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

---------- Edit #2 ----------

> I notice when I try a For Each ticket, I break it. Meaning it msgbox's
>   me each letter found. So If I had two tkt's in a string. - like: "I am
>   a ticket. My ticket is tkt8937378 and tkt89377786"

Here's a quick example of returning all the ticket numbers in the string:

```
    Dim strTEST As String = "I am a ticket. My ticket is tkt8937378. I am different ticket, called TKT411, in the same string." & vbCrLf _
        & "I'm a loner tKt911411311 on a different line!"
    Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(strTEST, "\btkt[0-9a-fA-F]+\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    While m.Success
        Dim ticket As String = m.Value
        Console.WriteLine(ticket)
        m = m.NextMatch
    End While
```

The same thing as above, but using a `For Each` with `Regex.Matches()` instead of `Match()`:

```
    Dim strTEST As String = "I am a ticket. My ticket is tkt8937378. I am different ticket, called TKT411, in the same string." & vbCrLf _
        & "I'm a loner tKt911411311 on a different line!"
    For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(strTEST, "\btkt[0-9a-fA-F]+\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Dim ticket As String = m.Value
        Console.WriteLine(ticket)
    Next
```

Comment: I am liking Regex now a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: Can you have multiple instances in this RegEx? for example to find both tkt and TKT? Or make it NON-Case sensitive?

Comment: Take a look at the edit above for options on how to make it case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks as always Idle_Mind

Comment: Here's the Microsoft specific [Regular Expression Language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation.

Comment: See Edit #2 for getting multiple matches.

Comment: Thanks Idle_Mind! I was going out of my mind with this. Regex new to me a bit but much easier...

Answer (score 1):

There is example :

```
        Dim strTEST As String = "I am a ticket. My ticket is tkt8937378"

        If strTEST.IndexOf("tkt") = -1 Then
            MsgBox("No ticket found")
        Else
            Dim res = Mid(strTEST, strTEST.IndexOf("tkt") + 1, Len(strTEST) - strTEST.IndexOf("tkt")).ToString.Split(" ")
            MsgBox("Ticket " & res(0) & " found.")
        End If
```

or You can use `Dim res = strTEST.Substring(strTEST.IndexOf("tkt"), Len(strTEST) - strTEST.IndexOf("tkt")).ToString.Split(" ")`